# Finding system stability

Tags: impulse-response, homework

LTI system with impulse response:

$h(t) = e^t \sin(-3t) \text{u}(-t)$

I know the rule and formula , but I am lost in how to do this because of the absolute. Please help.

Sorry if I posted in the wrong section.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do with this impulse response? What is "the absolute"?

Comment: the system is stable, **but** it is also anti-causal.  (it's not a real system that anyone can actually build, since it is predictive of the future input.)

Comment: @msm by "the absolute" meant the absolute on h(t) , [see navin's answer]

Comment: @robert yeah it is not causal, you know exams have weird stuff :)

Comment: @user6019827 Consider improving your post. I mean writing it in form of an actual question with the necessary details and also grammatically. $|h(t)|$ is read the absolute value of $h(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A system is stable if $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  |h(t) |dt < \infty$

In your case $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  |h(t) |dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  |e^t \sin(-3t)u(-t)| \ dt$

Since $\sin(-3t) = -\sin(3t)$,

$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} | e^t \sin(3t) u(-t)| \ dt$

$ = \int_{-\infty}^{0}  e^t |\sin(3t)| \ dt$ , $u(-t) = 1$ if $ -\infty < t < 0$ else $0$

$ < \int_{-\infty}^{0}  e^t \ dt < \infty$

So the system is stable.

Comment: Thank you, but I did not understand something: after we changed the bounds of the integral by u(-t) where did the sin(3t) go?

Comment: Integral with sin3t will be less than integral without sin3t which is less than infinity. So the integral with sin3t is also less than infinity..