# Stability of a signal

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals

I would like to know when I can determine that a system is stable. I've seen [Stability of a system](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37677/stability-of-a-system) but this is very theoretically. 
My background is that I've set up a measurement system to detect the signal changes of a gas sensor. Means, when I add such and that of a gas the sensor will change accordingly.

But when do I state that the signal I observe is stable? Per eyeballing it isn't that hard but I would like to use a better, more reproducible characteristic. A common thumb of rule is fine.

[image]

Comment: A system can be stable (as in that a bounded input signal never leads to unbounded output), a signal can't be. It's not a term that is applicable to signals.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I guess system and signal is quite convertible here? Or in other words: When is the system, represented by a signal, stable? When I only see the signal I have to use this as reference.

Comment: I'd argue that this is exactly the point where they are *not* convertible! But let's move forward here: I think you mean that this signal is the *impulse response* of your LTI system, is that right?

Comment: In that case, this [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35693/13320) answers your question with the harsh truth that an LTI system is stable if the integral over the absolute impulse response is finite – there's no thumbier rule than that!

Comment: @Ben It seems like you have a physical measurement setup. In that case, all the systems involved are stable: unstable systems don't exist in practice.

Comment: There's a terminology collision here, exacerbated by the fact that a lot of signal processing beginners don't understand what *system* stability means.  Are you, in fact, asking how to determine when your signal has settled out?  (Which is more or less a synonym of "stable" in the sense of "not moving", but doesn't overlap with "stable" in the systems sense of "doesn't move without external input")

Comment: Yes, seems so. I'd like to know when it has settled out.